# Tomcat7 common auth for multiple WebApps

Tags: authentication, tomcat7

I have to program multiple webapps on Tomcat7. They have to use one auth database and if the user has been logged in, there should have been only one session id (common session on multiple webapps?). In addition if the user loggen in on webapp A and go to webapp B they schould be already logged in on B (because it's the same account).

For now, I have one webapp that can auth user and two additional apps. But now, how to redirect from auth webapp to an other webapp and keep the session from auth app. Or if the user open app B, how to identify the user that is logged in on app A?

Have you any an idea how to manage this?

Edit: Or I have to store multiple session ids, one per webapp and identify a user via cookies? If user deactivated cookies they have to log in twice?

Comment: I think you are looking for a single sign on (SSO) solution like the [JASIG CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas) server.

Comment: Is there are no way to solve this native in tomcat7?

Comment: I don't think so. Webapps are sort of firewalled against each other. Otherwise one application might compromise the security model of another running in the same container.

Comment: Hmm, what do you think guys about common auth module via RMI? Or it is a fail concept?

Comment: I think you are trying to re-invent the wheel with that. Why not go for a readily available SSO solution?